# Best import file type / shading not displaying correct or editable

Tags: modeling

i was having so may issues i modelled the start of my work in skp, now it looks fine here but when imported to blender its not.i tried all the import types now & they all vary in what is shown in blender.

for example skp - dae 
its goes from smooth to faceted and i can't shade smooth in blender.. nothing happens

Also when i edit the vertices the face dont all move with the vert..i'm stuck as i camt seem to moel this is blender and i can import either..

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. *skp* == Sketchup? What export options do you have?

Comment: thanks i added the image, nothing is working. i'm following tutotials, none of the helping so far

Comment: There was a sketchup import addon in 2.79. Might worth to try that and open up the file in 2.8 otherwise dae and obj seems to be the best options. But do not expect that the geometry is the same (CAD vs Mesh modeling) so manual clean-up is always necessary.

Comment: The edges are likely marked as sharp. Have you tried switching into edit mode? Do you see any edges colored in blue? If that's the case you can select all edges and then use *Edge > Clear Sharp*.

Comment: thanks but nothing happens none of the tools seem to work on the model